# Multiple RadioButton Visibility Binding for a label

Tags: wpf

I am using a converter

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="convVisibility"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

I Have 3 radio buttons:

```
    <RadioButton Content="PRE" GroupName="Env" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="492,167,0,0" Name="radioButton4" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <RadioButton Content="POST" GroupName="Env" Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="558,167,0,0" Name="radioButton5" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <RadioButton Content="BOTH" GroupName="Env"  Height="16" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="632,167,0,0" Name="radioButton6" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

I have a label that I am trying to make visible if either radioButton4 or radioButton6 are selected. Currently can get it to work with 4 using this.

```
   <Label Content="PRE" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=radioButton4, Converter={StaticResource convVisibility}}" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="57,262,0,0" Name="label7" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

is there a way to add a second binding to the label or am I SOL, I have tried googling this for the past hour or so and expected it to be something simple, is it doable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding.aspx) with a custom [converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.imultivalueconverter.aspx) that `OR`'s the imput values from the bindings to the two `RadioButtons`.

```
<Label.Visibility>
    <MultiBinding>
        <MultiBinding.Converter>
            <local:LogicalOrConverter />
        </MultiBinding.Converter>
        <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="radioButton4"/>
        <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="radioButton6"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Label.Visibility>
```

Comment: I will have to look into custom converters when I get back on Monday. This is my first crack at WPF and so far it has been a ride...

Comment: @Contristo: I'd greatly recommend all the [overviews on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) by the way.

Comment: Awesome resource, I will make sure to check it out... I just officially brought my work home for the weekend. The wife is going to be thrilled...