# How to bind the Visibility-property of a label to many RadioButtons?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding

The Visibility-property of a Label can be connected to the IsChecked-property of a RadioButton using a BoolToVisiblityConverter. But how to connect one label's visibility to more than one IsChecked-property?

For Example `<Label Content="1"></Label>` should be visible when RadioButtons 1, 3 or 5 have IsChecked set to `true`, `<Label Content="2"></Label>` when RadioButtons 2 or 4 are checked.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel>
        <RadioButton Content="1"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="2"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="3"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="4"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton Content="5"></RadioButton>    
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
        <Label Content="1"></Label>
        <Label Content="2"></Label>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Comment: To help answering: Are you using the MVVM approach (meaning you have a view model controlling the UI) or do you rely on code-behind?

Comment: There will be no value add if done code behind.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple RadioButton Visibility Binding for a label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11696924/multiple-radiobutton-visibility-binding-for-a-label)

Comment: @GauravKP one should have a view model, of course. But this question is not the best place to explain the MVVM approach. Though this is solvable entirely in XAML, as the answer of the linked question shows.

Comment: @Spontifixus The link you had posted should resolve the issue. Great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a MultiDataTrigger to set the value entirely in Xaml without the use of a converter:

```
<StackPanel>
                <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton1" Content="1" />
                <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton2" Content="2" />
                <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton3" Content="3" />
                <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton4" Content="4" />
                <RadioButton x:Name="RadioButton5" Content="5" />
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                <Label x:Name="FirstLabel" Content="1">
                    <Label.Style>
                        <Style>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton3, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" />
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=RadioButton5, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True" />
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                        <Setter TargetName="FirstLabel" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Label.Style>
                </Label>
            </StackPanel>
```

Comment: it's good suggestion. But Conditions implementing AND relation. In my case I need to implemet OR Relation.

Comment: Then only add a simple DataTrigger for each condition.

Comment: Wow, it's very clever solution!

Comment: not works for me, TargetName in Setter cannot be used (vs 16.11.3), the member "Visibility" is not recognized

Answer (score 1):

When you want your `Label` to be visible when one from `RadioButton`s 1,3,5 is checked you can try this way.
Define a multibinding and a converter.
Converter:

```
public class LabelVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null) return false;
        return values.Any(v =>
        {
            bool? b = v as bool?;
            return b.HasValue && b.Value;
        });
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

This is an example. In Convert method we check whether any from values parameter is bool and has value true. Here is how to use the converter in markup:

```
<Grid>
<Grid.Resources>
    <conv:LabelVisibilityConverter x:Key="LabelConverter"/>
</Grid.Resources>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<StackPanel>
    <RadioButton x:Name="1" Content="1"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton x:Name="2" Content="2"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton x:Name="3" Content="3"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton x:Name="4" Content="4"></RadioButton>
    <RadioButton x:Name="5" Content="5"></RadioButton>    
</StackPanel>
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
    <Label Content="1">
        <Label.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LabelConverter}">
                <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="1"/>
                <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="3"/>
                <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="5"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Label.Visibility>
    </Label>
    <Label Content="2">
        <Label.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource LabelConverter}">
                <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="2"/>
                <Binding Path="IsChecked" ElementName="4"/>
            </MultiBinding>
        </Label.Visibility>         
    </Label>
</StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Don't forget to map a namespace of your converter (conv prefix) with:

```
xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:..."
```